# how to apply a function item by item in for loop in R

Tags: r

I have a complicated function that works on a matrix row by row. The function returns values that must be used as entries of the matrix rows, row by row. I need to use a `for` loop to make sure that these values are stored correctly. I cannot apply the function at once using a simple `lapply` or `for` loop, as there must be a condition based on the values of each row. Is there a way to run the `for` loop on each item and store the result in a matrix before moving to the next item? Note that this is different from my other posted question. My last question was on applying a condition on a matrix. However, here, I need to use a function on items and store them in a matrix, row by row.

In a simple way:

Here I have a list of vectors (stored in a list `x`).  I need the `for loop` to loop over each vector of `x` before moves to the elements of the second vector. For this case, I create an empty matrix (`Mat`). Then, I need to apply the square on the first vector of `x` (i.e, `c(1:4)`). Then, and before moving to square the next vector of `x`, if any entries of this row are `!= 0`, then the result is stored in `Mat` (last row (row `5`)), and the loop moves to the second vector. However, if all entries are `==0`, then the loop must stop and return me an empty matrix. If the result of the second vector is all `==0`, then the loop stores zeros to all rows (except the row `5`) of `Mat`. If not, then the loop moves to the third vector, and so on.

My code gives me an error `Error in Mat[k, i] <- res[[i]] :  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length In addition: Warning message: In seq_len(k - 1) : first element used of 'length.out' argument`

```
    x <- list(c(1:4), c(2,0,0), c(0,0,0), 0)
res <- list() ## I would like to store the result of squares. 
Mat <- matrix(0,5,5) ## here is the matrix where the result 
d <- 5
for(k in d:2){
for (i in seq_along(k-1)){
  res[[i]] <- x[[i]]^2 ## here I would like to find the result of the first item only before moving to the next one.
  Mat[k,i] <- res[[i]] ## store the result of the vector sas a row (bottom to top)
  if(all(setdiff(Mat[k,i], 0) == 0, na.rm = TRUE)){ ## if the result of the current vector is `0` then, I want to stop. The current row and coming rows set to zero. 
    Mat[k,] <- 0
    break 
  }
}
}

Expected result:

   
 Mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    4    0    0    0    0
[5,]    1    4    9    16    0
```

Comment: @akrun Hi. Could you please help me with this question. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you only trying to fill in the last row? You have `k <- 5:2` so when `i==`, you have `Mat[5:2, 1] <- res[[1]]`.  When you set up `Mat <- matrix(0, 0, 5)` you gave it zero rows. You can't assign to rows that don't exist.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for your comment. Sorry, It was a typo. I correct the matrix. `Mat<-matrix(0,5,5)`. My function automatically finds the result of one row at a time. However, as I must run the function over multiple rows, I need to use the `for` loop.

Comment: @MrFlick for `k <- d:2` this to store the result of the first run in `Mat[5,i]`

Comment: But if `k<-d:2`, that's the same as `k <- c(5,4,3,2)`. There's not just one value of `k`. You are looking at all 4 rows at once.

Comment: @MrFlick yes, you are correct. Sorry. I edit it.

Comment: @akrun Thanks a lot. I wrote to you before I got it. Thanks again. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try `for` loop like this

```
x <- list(c(1:4), c(2, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 0), 0)
Mat <- matrix(0, 5, 5)
for (k in seq_along(x)) {
    r <- x[[k]]^2
    if (any(r != 0)) {
        Mat[nrow(Mat) - k + 1, seq_along(r)] <- r
    } else {
        break
    }
}
```

which gives

```
> Mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    4    0    0    0    0
[5,]    1    4    9   16    0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great help. I have one question, does it find the result of each vector before moving to the second one, or it finds the whole result and then check the condition? if yes, I need to check the condition for each vector before moving to the second one.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Maryam One vector is checked before being added to `Mat`. If the check failed, then we stop the whole process, i.e., all the following vectors will be skipped.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that what I thought. My point is that the square of each vector should not be computed unless the previous vector passes the condition.  So, I think your solution find the squares for each item of all vectors. Then, if the vector does not pass the condition, then it is not listed. So, the `for` loop actually finds the item but not store them in the matrix unless they pass the condition, which is not my point. sorry.

Comment: @Maryam Yes, you can check the condition first and then do the square operation. Since `0^2` is still `0`, so it doesn't matter which order you take first.